# how to use double qoute parametrized function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

how to use double qoute parametrized function in jquery for html coding..

i have a function

```
 function ToggleDropDown(id1,id2);
 {
   var e = document.getElementById("" + id1+ "");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
   $("#" + id2 + "").text(strUser);
 }
```

now there is a jquery which build datagrid and combo button ..

```
 ....
 var control='<div class=...../* other code */>';
 controls += '<select id="GlobalFieldName" onchange=ToggleDropDown("GlobalFieldName","globalSelect");">';
```

now in html source file by firebug i got something like below code..

```
 <select id="GlobalFieldName" globalfieldname","globalselect");"=""   onchange="ToggleDropDown(">
 ......
```

i have to set double qoute in parameter of my function else  ihave to change in all other place which i dont want to do.. any idea..!!?

Comment: You can escape an `"` with a \ or use `'`. `'"'` and `"\""` are valid strings.

Comment: hey thanks buddy for yr time n reply.. its working :)

Comment: Quotes " and apostrophes ' are not valid characters in HTML IDs.. and may fail compatibility. Avoid colons as well, if possible -- they're allowed, but cause difficulties with CSS. See the HTML4 spec:  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
controls += '<select id="GlobalFieldName" data-file=\'"GlobalFieldName"\' data-select= \'"globalSelect"\' onchange=ToggleDropDown(this.getAttribute(\"data-file\",\"data-select\");">';
```